# Javascript Array sorting unique object with a key value condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, javascript-objects

I have an array

```
"datawithisNew": [
        {
            "exam_name": "MPSC",
            "isNew": false
        },
        
        {
            "exam_name": "MPSC",
            "isNew": true
        },
        {
            "exam_name": "UPSC",
            "isNew": false
        },
      
        {
            "exam_name": "RAILWAY",
            "isNew": false
        },
        {
            "exam_name": "RAILWAY",
            "isNew": false
        }]
```

I am trying to get a result with unique `exam_name` such that the resulted array of objects hold unique `exam_name` values also if the `exam_name` has atleast 1 `isNew` key as true, the resulted object should have the property with `isNew` `true`, if not `false`.
The expected result -

```
"datawithisNew": [
        {
            "exam_name": "MPSC",
            "isNew": true
        },

        {
            "exam_name": "UPSC",
            "isNew": false
        },
        {
            "exam_name": "RAILWAY",
            "isNew": false
        }]
```

The code i am using is-

```
 var helper1 = {};
    var result2 = data12.reduce(function(r, o) {
    var key = o.exam_name ;
    
    if(!helper1[key]) {
      helper1[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
      r.push(helper1[key]);
    } else {
      helper1[key].exam_name_rating += o.exam_name_rating;
    }
    return r;
  }, []);
```

But this just return the unique `exam_name` object i also need `isNew` key if it occurs atleast `true` atleast once for the `exam_name` it should have `isNew:true` as true or else `isNew:false`

Comment: Please share your code, along with the problems you've encountered while trying to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where not far from the actual solution, adding the line below solves your problem:

```
helper1[key].isNew ||= o.isNew;
```

`||=` will assign a variable or property to a value if the current value is falsy.

If you cannot use the [logical OR assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) (`||=`) operator due to it being a fairly new assignment operator you can use:

```
if (!helper1[key].isNew) helper1[key].isNew = o.isNew;
```

```js
const data12 = [
  { "exam_name": "MPSC",    "isNew": false },
  { "exam_name": "MPSC",    "isNew": true  },
  { "exam_name": "UPSC",    "isNew": false },
  { "exam_name": "RAILWAY", "isNew": false },
  { "exam_name": "RAILWAY", "isNew": false },
];

var helper1 = {};
var result2 = data12.reduce(function(r, o) {
  var key = o.exam_name ;

  if(!helper1[key]) {
    helper1[key] = Object.assign({}, o); // create a copy of o
    r.push(helper1[key]);
  } else {
    helper1[key].exam_name_rating += o.exam_name_rating;
    helper1[key].isNew ||= o.isNew; // <- added this line
  }
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result2);
```

Since the example data does not contain the `exam_name_rating` property, it will be either missing, or set to `NaN` for the result. I assume this property is available within your own data.

Comment: Yes, that property was also available in my data, and you have made this easier for me for addition in the code which i was using. Thanks this helped

Comment: Check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment#Browser_compatibility) to see what engines currently support this operator. Currently it is not supported by Internet Explorer, Opera, Samsung Internet and Node.JS. If this is a problem go for the alternative solution. If you are using a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), you don't have to worry about compatibility.

Comment: The operator wasn't working as i am using nodejs, but the alternative solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use JS `Array.filter` to filter out duplicates

```js
const datawithisNew = [{
    "exam_name": "MPSC",
    "isNew": false
  },

  {
    "exam_name": "MPSC",
    "isNew": true
  },
  {
    "exam_name": "UPSC",
    "isNew": false
  },

  {
    "exam_name": "RAILWAY",
    "isNew": false
  },
  {
    "exam_name": "RAILWAY",
    "isNew": false
  }
];

const uniqueItems = datawithisNew.filter((exam, index, self) => {
  return self.findIndex(e => exam.exam_name === e.exam_name) === index
}).map(exam => {
  if (!exam.isNew && datawithisNew.find(e => e.exam_name === exam.exam_name && e.isNew)) {
    exam.isNew = true;
  }
  return exam;

});



console.log(uniqueItems);
```

Comment: it works for unique exam_name key i also need the second key isNew if it exists with true value atleast for once or else as false

Comment: @pse run now, it will give you unique keys and will also set isNew to true if any of the exam has it to true

Answer (score 1):

Call this below function with your datawithisNew as a parameter

```
     function getUniqueExams(data){
let finalObjMap = { };
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
let currentObj = data[i];
if(finalObjMap[currentObj["exam_name"]])
{
if(!finalObjMap[currentObj["isNew"]] && currentObj["isNew"])
    finalObjMap[currentObj["exam_name"]]["isNew"]=true;
}
else
{
    finalObjMap[currentObj["exam_name"]]={"isNew":currentObj["isNew"]};
}

}
let finalData=[];
Object.keys(finalObjMap).forEach((key)=>{
let tempExamObj  = { "exam_name": key , "isNew": finalObjMap[key]["isNew"]};
finalData.push(tempExamObj);

});
return finalData;
};

    var datawithisNew=[
            {
                "exam_name": "MPSC",
                "isNew": false
            },
            
            {
                "exam_name": "MPSC",
                "isNew": true
            },
            {
                "exam_name": "UPSC",
                "isNew": false
            },
          
            {
                "exam_name": "RAILWAY",
                "isNew": false
            },
            {
                "exam_name": "RAILWAY",
                "isNew": false
            }];
    console.log(getUniqueExams(datawithisNew));
```

Comment: Its failing a test case if we interchange the indexes of objects eg: when 0th in 1st first place and 1st in 0th place

Comment: You were right , edited the post , please try now. Thanks for the correction :)

Comment: This code worked too, but sorry i will accept the other one as it is a few line code which will work for me. but thankyou for your time